# UIPopoverController isPopoverVisible returns wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

```
if([messageNotification isPopoverVisible])
    [messageNotification dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

I have the above two lines of code in my project where `message_Notification` is a `UIPopovercontroller`'s object.

The problem is `isPopoverVisible` returns `false` when my Popover actually presented on the main viewController. Any idea about this??

Comment: I think there is no bug with isPopoverVisible property. Just show us more code to clarify what is messageNotification please.

Answer (score 0):

Check that message_Notification is available or not and then check for visiblity
And I think there is some inconsistency because messageNotification and message_Notification should be same as I have done in my code

```
    if(messageNotification)
    {
         if([messageNotification isPopoverVisible])
         {
            [messageNotification dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
         }
    }
   else
   {
     NSLog(@"Not availble");
   }
```